# IE7: ActiveX Information Bar for Ajax website without ActiveX

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, activex, diagnostics, information-bar

We're deploying to our intranet (Internet Explorer 7) an ASP.NET webapp which we created and which we know **does not contain ActiveX in any way**.  A yellow "Information Bar" is appearing when the webapp loads in the browser, with the following message:

> Your security settings do not allow
>   websites to use ActiveX controls
>   installed on your computer.  The page
>   may not display correctly.  Click here
>   for options...

Clicking (or right-clicking) on the bar gives only stock Help content.  How can I learn more information about the ActiveX control IE thinks is trying to load?

How can I learn the name of the control?  Or its publisher?  Or its location on disk?

Comment: It uses Ajax (Telerik RAD Controls, mostly).  I don't know if that's causing XmlHttpRequest.  Otherwise, I don't know XmlHttpRequest to be used at all.

Comment: Yes, AJAX will use XMLHttpRequest. Ideally an AJAX framework should attempt to use native XMLHttpRequest first, falling back to ActiveX XMLHttpRequest for IE6, but some may go for the ActiveX version first, causing the unnecessary prompt in IE7.

Comment: This gives me a new troubleshooting angle.  I've added the "ajax" keyword to the question title.  I'd love to hear anyone else's ideas.